# Compiling *.ins files in MiKTeX 2.9

Tags: packages, installing, miktex

I am trying to install the [`hieroglf`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hieroglf) package on my PC.  I am running MiKTeX 2.9.

When I try to run `latex hieroglf.ins` I get an error message indicating that the file can not be found.  I know the file is in the directory in which I am working.

This appears to be the same issue as the one indicated here:

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54821/compiling-an-ins-file-into-a-sty-file

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Comment: Why don't you just use the miktex package manager to install it. Just install the `archaic` package. For the most part, stuff on CTAN can be installed directly via the manager.

Comment: If your .ins is in a similar folder that in the question you linked too: Miktex won't find files inside a miktex tree if you haven't updated the FNDB fist. Or better:  move the .ins to some temporary folder and compile there.

Answer (score 1):

If your `.ins` is in a similar folder than in the question you linked to: Miktex won't find files inside a miktex tree if you haven't updated the FNDB first. Or better: move the `.ins` to some temporary folder and compile there.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using texstudio you can get the answer in this video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LmVNYENkWF4